# Is it possible to set MobaXterm for use a bash history in a terminal session?

Tags: bash, mobaxterm

I want to be able to save command history in a session. I have even created the file, but the session does not save it. How can I do this?

Comment: Go to Settings/General and set your "persistent Home directory"

Comment: That wasn't enough, if I close the app, I lost the session